# Not able to set interval on socket.io event

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, websocket, socket.io

Is there a way to split and loop over each client while maintaining control of timing? I need to emit all tweets but with a set time in between each one. Here's the code so far that throws an exception:

```
var socketList = new Array();
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socketList.push(socket);
});

setInterval(function() {
    socketList.forEach('tweet', function(tweet) {
        io.sockets.emit('info', {tweet: tweet});
    });
}, 2000);
```

This code works but streams the tweets too quickly:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
    stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
        socket.emit('info', {tweet: tweet});
    });
});
```

**EDIT** This code doesn't give any errors but doesn't stream any tweets:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'lol' })

var socketList = new Array();
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socketList.push(socket);
});

function EmitTweets() {
    stream.socketList.forEach('tweet', function(tweet) {
        io.sockets.emit('info', {tweet: tweet});
    });
    setTimeout(EmitTweets, 1000);
}
```

Not sure where else to call "stream"

Comment: Did you find out the issue and a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is synchronous. Try this:

```
function emitTweets() {
  socketList.forEach('tweet', function(tweet) {
    io.sockets.emit('info', { tweet: tweet });
  });

  // this is the part that makes it repeat
  setTimeout(emitTweetes, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm almost there. It doesn't give any errors after setTimeout, but tweets aren't emitting. Please see my updated code. Where would I have to call stream?

Comment: I just realized, this is more complicated then I thought. Tweets are coming in at there own pace, and you are trying to emit them slower then they come. But that's a problem, because what happens to the tweets that come during the timeout? For now, I can't figure out a good solution, sorry.

Comment: Helps me understand the problem, I appreciate it.